# Javascript - PHP's Substr() alternative on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, string

I am working with a long string on javasctipt and I have to replace substrings that I cant predetermine their length and value , where I can't use `str.replace(/substr/g,'new string')`, which doesn't allow replacing a substring that I can just determine its start position and its length.

Is there a function that I can use like `string substr (string, start_pos, length, newstring)` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combo of `substr` and concatenation using `+` like this:

```js
function customReplace(str, start, end, newStr) {
  return str.substr(0, start) + newStr + str.substr(end);
}


var str = "abcdefghijkl";

console.log(customReplace(str, 2, 5, "hhhhhh"));
```

Comment: this won't work if `newStr` argument is not passed in: `console.log(customReplace(str, 2, 5));` gives `abundefinedfghijkl`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest if `newStr` is not passed in then what is the point of the function itself?

Comment: you should consider this condition to get a more uniform solution

Answer (score 2):

There is no build-in function which replaces with new content based on index and length. Extend the prototype of string(or simply define as a function) and generate the string using  [`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method.

```js
String.prototype.customSubstr = function(start, length, newStr = '') {
  return this.substr(0, start) + newStr + this.substr(start + length);
}

console.log('string'.customSubstr(2, 3, 'abc'));

// using simple function
function customSubstr(string, start, length, newStr = '') {
  return string.substr(0, start) + newStr + string.substr(start + length);
}

console.log(customSubstr('string', 2, 3, 'abc'));
```

Comment: i want to replace with other charachters

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you have `substr` and `substring`:

```js
var str = "mystr";
console.log(str.substr(1, 2));
console.log(str.substring(1, 2));
```

They differ on the second parameter. For `substr` is length (Like the one you asked) and for `substring` is last index position. You don't asked for the second one, but just to document it.

Comment: is there anyway to use them to replace a string or characters by other ones?

Comment: Yes, you have to substring to the index you want and concatenate it to the next. Actually, this answer is pretty good: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42300623/1525495